# Cross PDO driver compatible GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlite, postgresql, pdo

Is there an efficient alternative to `GROUP_CONCAT` that works in the major PDO drivers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this MySQL:

```
select group_concat(c separator ',') from t
```

you could do this in PostgreSQL:

```
select array_to_string(array_agg(c), ',') from t
```

or this in SQLite:

```
select group_concat(c, ',') from t
```

I don't know about SQL Server though.

References:

- [MySQL `group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
- [PostgreSQL `array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE)
- [PostgreSQL `array_to_string`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)
- [SQLite `group_concat`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat)

Comment: Brilliant! I can implement each variant on my database driver wrapper classes. It's for an open source project so I'll let somebody else implement mssql version if it's needed. I don't tend to use mssql much these days

Comment: @Lea: You might want to do a version check on the PostgreSQL version, the one I gave works in 9.0, let me know if you need to support 8 and I'll see what I can do.